# Websocket onopen fires but not onmessage when put on a separate javascript file .Net Core Razor

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, websocket, razor-pages

I am trying to get messages from a websocket. If I place my javascript code inside the .cshtml file the onopen and onmessage events fire correctly. If I place the same code inside a separate javascript file and include it in the page file onopen fires correctly but onmessage never fires.
Code in cshtml file:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/klines-graph.js"></script>
<script>
   var klines = new Klines('@Model.Symbol', '5m');
   klines.createKlines();
</script>
```

Code in javascript file:

```
class Klines {
    constructor(symbol, interval) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.interval = interval;
        this.currentPrice = 0;
        this.sum = 0;
        this.onPriceChange = new Event('onPriceChange');
        this.liveKlineSocket = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/' + symbol + '@@kline_5m');
        const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
            layout: {
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                textColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
            },
            grid: {
                vertLines: {
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
                },
                horzLines: {
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
                },
            },
            crosshair: {
                mode: LightweightCharts.CrosshairMode.Normal,
            },
            //localization: {
            //    priceFormatter: price => {
            //        return parseFloat(price).toFixed(10);
            //    },
            //},
            timeScale: {
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
                timeVisible: true,
                secondsVisible: false,
            },
        });
        this.candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries(
            //{
            //    candle customization
            //    upColor: 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)',
            //    downColor: '#000',
            //    borderDownColor: 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)',
            //    borderUpColor: 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)',
            //    wickDownColor: 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)',
            //    wickUpColor: 'rgba(255, 144, 0, 1)',
            //}
        );
    }

    

    createKlines() {
        fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${this.symbol}&interval=${this.interval}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(klineData => {
                let candleStickList = klineData.map(item => {
                    return {
                        "time": item[0] / 1000,
                        "open": item[1],
                        "high": item[2],
                        "low": item[3],
                        "close": item[4]
                    };

                });
                this.candleSeries.setData(candleStickList);
                this.currentPrice = candleStickList[candleStickList.length - 1].close;

                this.liveKlineSocket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
                    console.log('Connected to kline websocket');                  
                });
                this.liveKlineSocket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
                    console.log('message');
                    let candleStick = JSON.parse(event.data);
                    this.candleSeries.update({
                        time: candleStick.openTime / 1000,
                        open: candleStick.open,
                        high: candleStick.high,
                        low: candleStick.low,
                        close: candleStick.close
                    });
                });
            }).catch(er => {
                console.log(er);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me is there any error thrown inside the browser?

Comment: @BrandoZhang There is no error. It just doesn't fire. The weirdest thing is that onopen works correctly.